# How to access WSL PATH from Powershell core?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

If I open up the Ubuntu app (terminal) and type `echo $PATH`, I get a bunch of directories. If I type `wsl echo $PATH` in Powershell core, I get absolutely nothing (a blank row). I would like to run a Linux command from Powershell core, how do I do that?

Comment: Also see [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/1664131/1210833) for some other aspects of running Linux commands (such as `ls -lh` in this case) from PowerShell via WSL.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `.bashrc` isn't run when you just run `wsl <command>`, you need to run `wsl bash -c '<command>'`, or run `<command>` while inside a bash shell.